# How to get and output the current value of my odometer on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to 1) get and 2) output the current value of my odometer on button click? The snipet which should do that is at the bottom of the JavaScript but it does not work.

My code: https://jsfiddle.net/aht87opr/8/

Documentation of odometer might come in handy:
http://brock-family.org/gavin/software/web/odometer.html (where it says "Get the current value from the odometer: val = myOdometer->get();")

```
//My attempt to output the current value from the odometer:
$('button').click(function() {
   n = myOdometer.get();
   return n;
});
```

Comment: try pushing the value into something like a known element, a Form field, or a global, or post the value to your server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just use `myOdometer.get()`, which already gives you the number you are looking for.

If you want to put the value inside the `#value` element you can use the following:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var mefedron = myOdometer.get();
    $('#value').text(mefedron);
});
```

Here is the fix in your jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/aht87opr/14/

Comment: Great! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Beat me to it!!

Comment: @KazekageGaara almost at the same time :) you'll have my vote there

Comment: @Dekel one more thing....I want browser cookies to remember the number so each time the user visits the site , the odometer will resume on the value on which it stopped when the user left the site. Is is easy or hard to do ? I am not javascript ninja, only a beginner still learning

Comment: This is a complete different question, you should open a new one. with the relevant information.

Comment: Cookies are easy to write, not so easy to read as you have to manually parse them.  localstorage is another option, but like @Dekel say's another question would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/6abu3ruf/ (you'll have to fix the CSS)

There are two issues with the fiddle you shared:

1. You don't have to do `mefedron.val();`, `mefedron` has the value you are looking for.
2. You are not setting that value anywhere.

So basically, just change your onclick to:

```
$('button').click(function() {
   var mefedron = myOdometer.get(n);
   $("#value").text(mefedron);
});
```

Comment: @KazekageGaara--> one more thing....I want browser cookies to remember the number so each time the user visits the site , the odometer will resume on the value on which it stopped when the user left the site.. Is is easy or hard to do ? I am not javascript ninja, only a beginner still learning

Answer (score 0):

just update your button event handler with the following:

```
$('button').click(function() {
     var mefedron = myOdometer.get(n);
      mefedron=  Math.round(mefedron * 100) / 100
      $("#value").text(mefedron)


    });
```

Here is a working version of the code hosted on jsFiddle [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dawith/aht87opr/16/)

Comment: And you didn't get error on `mefedron.val()`? Did you check other answers here?

Comment: yap, I just checked my console and I got an error. I have updated myself solution.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and `confirm(Math.floor(mefedron*10));` works.

```
$('button').click(function() {
      var mefedron = myOdometer.get(n);
      confirm(Math.floor(mefedron*10)); // it works
      function number() {
      return mefedron.val();
        }
        number();

    });
```

So, if you just want to return the odometer, then on the button click event just return `Math.floor(mefedron*10)`;

To display it on div#value, `$("div#value").html(Math.floor(mefedron*10));`